# Mutating method sent to immutable object

Tags: ios, json, parsing, class-method

I'm using JSONKit to parse a JSON string returned from my server in my iPhone application. Part of the server response is a couple of Base64 encoded images that I want to decode into actual images and add to the object that the parser creates. The problem is I can't seem to figure out what kind of class the parser returns, and thus what kind of methods that can be used to interact with the object. I've searched the [JSONKit documentation](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit/blob/master/README.md) for answers to my question, but haven't found it.

```
decodedData = [[request responseString] objectFromJSONString];

int i = 0;
[Base64 initialize];
for (NSString *base64String in [decodedData valueForKey:@"base64String"]) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[Base64 decode:base64String]];
    [decodedData setValue:image forKey:@"image"];
    i++;
}
```

This code is placed in a method that gets called when the request has successfully finished and the response is returned in `[request responseString]` (the JSON). The `decodedData` object's class is defined in the header file. No matter what I declare it as (either `NSArray`, `NSMutableArray`, `NSDictionary`, or `NSMutableDictionary`) I get the same error when the code is run (it compiles just fine), which is:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '*** -[JKDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
```

Can anybody tell me what kind of class the object is, and what I should do to add the Base64-decoded image to the object?

I'm pretty new to Objective-C, so bear over with me. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're trying to mutate the immutable `JKDictionary` (itself a proxy for an immutable `NSDictionary` object).

The documentation you linked to specifies an instance method on `NSString` named `- (id)mutableObjectFromJSONString;`, this will give you a mutable dictionary object that you can play with if you so desire.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm.